# DomPDF Issue - Random blank pages on huge PDF

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, pdf-generation, dompdf

I've been using **DomPDF** within CodeIgniter to generate a catalogue with over 200 pages of data. Within this there are many, many tables with multiple styles attached to them.

Although I'm not using any CSS `page-break` attributes, it seems there are random spurs of **blank pages** spread throughout the generated document. Sometimes even 15 in a row. Is there any explanation as to why this is happening or any potential fixes that anyone knows of?

I can't seem to find anyone else who is having a similar problem so I have no reference.

**The generation code used in the view can be found here:**
https://gist.github.com/sixteenstudio/22e7027706defd8df35b

**And the DomPDF generation initialization code looks like this:**

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("catalogue.pdf");
```

Comment: Using dompdf to regularly create large 200+ page report pdf's too never had this issue it only adds a page either when a table wraps across multiple pages or when I tell it to issue a page break with the css page-break tag.  Can you post up your code both the HTML generation and the dompdf call bit (even though thats only like 5 lines) so I can see if there's anything obviously wrong.

Comment: There is an insane amount of dynamically generated HTML, over 18,000 lines in fact. I'll edit the main post with the view.php script if that's any use to you? It includes all the tags, just all of the text/image content is php echoed.

Comment: At a guess one of your if's isn't closing properly on a rare case leaving unclosed table tags which is all gathering up and being rendered in as blank pages. dump out the generated html to a text area then run the generated html through a validator to check its all valid see if that resolves the issue.  the other thing is you're using child and inherited css classes I'm not 100% sure dompdf supports those as it doesn't support the full css spec in conversion so it may be ignoring tags generating excessive padding and again dumping it all at once into blank pages.

Comment: Can you extract a section from the larger HTML document that still exhibits the problem? I have seen this before in the past, though it's been a while since I've dealt with the issue. Usually it relates to page-break styling, but it could be an element that's too large for a page that dompdf has trouble breaking up, or even just a style that dompdf isn't handling correctly.

Comment: just render HTML and post it to pastebin or somewhere if its possible (data are right protected or something)

Comment: Ok, it seems the issue was with tables spanning more than one page. Whenever a table was too long & contained too many options, it would break. The way I realised this was by making the font very small and realising that only the absolutely huge tables would cause this problem. This was fixed by splitting the tables out when they became too long, but now I'm left with another issue. I need to build a table of contents but there are no documented functions for grabbing page numbers from anchors. Can anyone possibly shed any light on this issue or perhaps someone who has done it before?

Comment: @BrianS Would it be possible to get your direct assistance in the Google Group if I pop over and post a question? It seems you have extremely extensive knowledge on the usage of DomPDF, and I have a couple of questions I'd like to pose

Comment: @SixteenStudio I'm on the dev team (mostly supporting users these days). The other dev has more knowledge of the programming internals, but I'm a pretty good hack. I watch the Google group so feel free to move over there (it's better for general discussion).

Comment: @BrianS any chance I could grab your assistance in chat for a minute? It would be much quicker as I have a feeling you may have already seen a new issue I'm having.

Comment: @SixteenStudio sure, preferred forum?

Comment: @BrianS php if possible

Comment: @SixteenStudio http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38344/dompdf-issue-random-blank-pages-on-huge-pdf